# Pulling Data From Multiple Tables in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I'm kind of new to Django and am having some trouble pulling from existing tables.  I'm trying to pull data from columns on multiple joined tables.  I did find a solution, but it feels a bit like cheating and am wondering if my method below is considered proper or not.

```
class Sig(models.Model):
        sig_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
        state = models.CharField(max_length=2, db_column='state')
        release_id = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=releaseChoices)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
        phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        fax = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        contactname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        ratinggroup = models.BooleanField()
        state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, db_column='state_id')
        usesigrating = models.BooleanField()
        major = models.BooleanField()
        class Meta:
            db_table = u'sig'

    class SigCategory(models.Model):
        sig_category_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        sig = models.ForeignKey(Sig, related_name='sigcategory')
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        class Meta:
            db_table = u'sig_category'

    class Category(models.Model):
        category_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        release_id = models.SmallIntegerField()
        class Meta:
            db_table = u'category'
```

Then, this was my solution, which works, but doesn't quite feel right:

```
sigs = Sig.objects.only('sig_id', 'name').extra(
            select = {
                'category': 'category.name',
            },
        ).filter(
            sigcategory__category__category_id = categoryId,
            state_id = stateId
        ).order_by('sigcategory__category__name', 'name')
```

Now since the items in filter() join the sigcategory and category models, I was able to pull category.name out by using extra().  Is this a proper way of doing this?  What if I did not have the reference in filter() and the join did not take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SigCategory` has a ForeignKey pointing at Category, so you can *always* get from the SigCategory to the Category simply by doing `mysigcategory.category` (where `mysigcategory` is your instance of SigCategory.

If you haven't previously accessed that relationship from that instance, doing it here will cause an extra database lookup - if you're concerned about db efficiency, look into `select_related`.

Comment: However, if I try and jump that relationship with something like this: sigs[0].sigcategory.category, I just end up with this exception: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'category'

Comment: That's because there can be many sigcategories. It's not an instance, it's a manager. Try `sigs[0].sigcategory.all()[0].category` instead.

Comment: I can't believe that escaped me.  Thanks guys.